# Difference in interface and implementation section having {$R *.DFM} directive

Tags: delphi

Difference between having `{$R *.DFM}` directive in interface and implementation section?

what if i have `{$R *.DFM}` in interface?

```
interface
{$R *.DFM}
```

what if i have `{$R *.DFM}` in implementation?

```
implementation
{$R *.DFM}
```

Comment: no difference AFAIK. the compiler links the the resource/s to the executable in both cases (and that's it).

Comment: As @kobik says, no difference. It seems to me that you could have answered this yourself by cutting and pasting a single line (`{$R *.dfm}` and building your app.

Comment: @Ken: Not really. He could have seen that there are no differences that are **obvious to him**.

Comment: @Uli: No, he could have seen that regardless of where that statement is placed, the form is still available and functions normally. Since `{$R *.DFM}` is only used to include the IDE generated form file, there could not be any differences. I do agree with Rob though, that it belongs to the IDE and should just be left alone.

Comment: @Ken, just because the program continues to run normally doesn't rule out *other* differences that aren't perceptible. For example, *maybe* the statement being in the implementation section means that only code from the current unit can access that resource. That's all ordinary programs ever do, so the casual observer would never notice a difference if it were put somewhere else. You and I know that's not how resources work, but it's not obvious to someone who doesn't already know the answer to the question.

Comment: @Rob: It's a form file (.DFM), so its contents are pretty clear. If the form gets created and appears correctly, and the event handlers get attached properly, it works. I didn't downvote the question; I merely pointed out that many times you can do something yourself to find an answer before posting here. In this case, that single experiment would have provided the answer that *functionally* there is no difference in the location, although your comment about that line belonging to the IDE was correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't make any difference. That instruction ensure that the DFM resource associated with that unit's form gets linked to your executable. All units have access to all resources in the program, so the location of the linking instruction has no effect on the visibility of the resource.

That instruction is placed by the IDE. The IDE can act strangely if you move parts of your code that it's responsible for, so I don't recommend moving the `$R` command, even if the compiler accepts it anywhere. Leave it wherever you found it.

Comment: Where do you think the IDE places it typically for Form units? I observe it after the `uses` declaration of the `implementation` section. Sometimes after `var` sometimes even after normal functions, but this is obviously caused by hand. Is there a "canonical position" for it?